# BT's 5 static IPs over PPPoE with TP Link Dual WAN TL-ER6020 router

Tags: router, nat, static-ip, tp-link

Recently i bought nice dual WAN router TP Link TL-ER6020 to use it with two BT(British Telecom) Infinity Broadband lines with Openreach VDSL modems (Huawei HG612 , unlocked, as told Ebay seller).

One of the broadband lines (WAN1) has 5 static ips:
ip range: 92.X.X.129 - 92.X.X.133
subnet mask: 255.255.255.248
gateway ip: 92.X.X.134

Router supports following connection types: Static IP, Dynamic IP, PPPoE, L2TP and PPTP. I have to use PPPoE Protocol to connect to Internet. And it works.

But... To use static Ip (assign them to devices) i have to use "One to One NAT" router's feature. 
Here is a problem. "One to One NAT" works only with Static IP connection mode (not PPPoE).

**Question:** is any way to setup Openreach Huawei HG612 modem to connect using PPPoE then connect TP Link TL-ER6020 to it using Static IP mode? Or maybe other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appear you have the 92.x.x.128 /29 network block assigned with 92.x.x.134 as the router address.  Just configure your servers with the ip address you want, 92.x.x.134 as the router address and 255.225.255.248 as the netmask.

There should be no need for NAT.